# Is it possible to know if the node where a Kubernetes Pod is being scheduled is master or worker?

Tags: kubernetes, daemonset

I'm currently using Kubernetes to schedule a DaemonSet on both master and worker nodes.

The DaemonSet definition is the same for both node types (same image, same volumes, etc), the only difference is that when the entrypoint is executed, I need to write a different configuration file (which is generated in Python with some dynamic values) if the node is a master or a worker.

Currently, to overcome this I'm using two different DaemonSet definitions with an env value which tells if the node is a master or not. Here's the yaml file (only relevant parts):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: worker-ds
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: worker
spec:
  ...
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
        - name: my-image
          ...
          env:
            - name: NODE_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.hostIP
            - name: IS_MASTER
              value: "false"
      ...
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: master-ds
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: master
spec:
  ...
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        operator: Exists
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
        - name: my-image
          ...
          env:
            - name: NODE_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.hostIP
            - name: IS_MASTER
              value: "true"
      ...
```

However, since the only difference is the **IS_MASTER** value, I want to collapse both the definitions in a single one that programmatically understands if the current node where the pod is being scheduled is a master or a worker.

Is there any way to know this information about the node programmatically (even reading a configuration file [for example something that only the master has or viceversa] in the node or something like that)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a convenient way to access the node information in pod.

If you only want a single `DaemonSet` definition, you can add a `sidecar` container to your pod, the `sidecar` container can [access the k8s api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod), then your main container can get something useful from the `sidecar`.

By the way, I think your current solution is properly :)

Comment: I see... Yeah, I think that the sidecar container solution is a bit too much, since I need this information only when running the entrypoint script. If there are no alternatives, I think I'll stay with my current solution for now. Thanks for you reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can tell a node is the master if it has the label `node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""`.
What you need to do is access that label from your containers which can be done with the [Downward Api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/) (**Edit: Wrong, only Pod information can be accessed from the Downward Api**). You can mount the labels inside your containers using:

```
volumes:
    - name: podinfo
      downwardAPI:
        items:
          - path: "labels"
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.labels
```

You can then search the content of that file from within the container.

Comment: I think `Downward API` can allow access pod informatin, not node information

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @menya, Downward API allows to access to pod information unfortunately :( Thanks for the reply anyways! :)

Comment: My apologies, that's an oversight on my part.